# only text value of element through xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a below XML. I want to get the text value of Title element. I have used `<xsl:value-of select="Title/text()"/>`,But it does not fetch the output.

```
XML-
<Section>
<Chapter>
<Title>
<Marker>MarkerText1</Marker>some text1
</Title>
</Chapter>
<Chapter>
<Title>
<Marker>MarkerText2</Marker>sometext2
<Marker>MarkerText3</Marker>some text3
</Title>
</Chapter>
</Section>
```

I have used below XSL but it does not fetch any results. And when I used `Title/text()[last()]` then it gives the last value. I mean `text()[last()]` is working but not just `text()`

```
<xsl:template match="/Section/Chapter">                         
    <xsl:value-of select="Title/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Output should contain:

```
<Title>some text1</Title><Title>some text2 sometext3</Title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 1.0, then the `value-of` a node set is the string value of its first node in document order.  So

```
<xsl:value-of select="Title/text()"/>
```

will give you the value of the *first* child text node under the *first* (in this case only) `Title` element under the current context node.  For the `Chapter` elements in your example this would be the text node between the opening `<Title>` tag and the opening `<Marker>` tag, which consists of a single newline character.

XSLT 2.0 is different, in that case `value-of` would give you the values of *all* the selected nodes, separated by spaces, for the first `Chapter` this would be newline, space, some text1, newline.

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0, when I use <xsl:value-of select="Title/text()"/> output shows nothing.

Comment: This is the stylesheet which I am using:<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 
                <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
               
                <xsl:template match="/Section/Chapter">
                               
                                <xsl:value-of select="Title/text()"/>
                </xsl:template>
 
   </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @Ankit the output doesn't show "nothing", it will show the value of the first text node under the `Title`, which in this case happens to be entirely whitespace.

Comment: @Ankit if you use `apply-templates` or `copy-of` instead of `value-of` then it should include all the selected text nodes rather than just the first one.

Comment: Isn't there any way by using Value-of to get the output

Comment: @Ankit you could `for-each` over the text nodes and take the `value-of` each one in turn, but that's essentially what `<xsl:apply-templates select="Title/text()" />` does for you.

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates select="Title/text()" /> works, thanks Ian :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by the "text value", but if you mean the same as what the spec calls the "string value", then use

```
<xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
```

If that's not what you want then you need to explain your desired output more clearly.

Comment: Sir I only want the value of <Title> tag only, not the text value of <marker> tag in it.If I were to use <xsl:value-of select="Title"/> it will give the text value of <marker> tag as well.

Comment: output should contain:<Title>some text1</Title><Title>some text2 sometext3</Title>

Comment: Then you're best off using apply-templates to process all the children/descendants recursively, with template rules to match each kind of node you might encounter.

Answer (score 0):

**This XML input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Section>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>
      <Marker>MarkerText1</Marker>some text1
    </Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>
      <Marker>MarkerText2</Marker>some text2
      <Marker>MarkerText3</Marker>some text3
    </Title>
  </Chapter>
</Section>
```

**Provided to this XSLT transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Titles>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Titles>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Title">
    <Title><xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/></Title>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Title/text()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Yields this XML output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Titles>
   <Title>some text1
    </Title>
   <Title>some text2
      some text3
    </Title>
</Titles>
```

Explanation:

- The `match="/"` template establishes a root element for the produced
  `Title` elements.  (The rootless sequence of `Title` elements you mention in
  your question would not be well-formed XML.)
- The `match="Title"` template generates the requested `Title` elements
  and applies pattern matching on the contained `text()` nodes.
- The `match="Title/text()` template copies over text nodes that are
  children of `Title` elements in the input XML.

**If you'd prefer your output to look like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Titles>
   <Title>some text1</Title>
   <Title>some text2 some text3</Title>
</Titles>
```

**You can use this slightly more complicated template for `match="Title/text()"`:**

```
  <xsl:template match="Title/text()">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::text()">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>
```